# nodejs commander.js 'alias' not working as expected for "--help"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with commander.js for my project and I am facing a weird issue when giving an alias for a command. I referred to examples mentioned here: [Commander.JS Example](https://github.com/tj/commander.js)

I am looking for creating a git like command so I started with the `.command()` method. When I clone the above repo and run it locally for the given example of `pm`, the help option works as expected. Note that in usage section there is only 'pm' and the command 'install' has alias 'i' separated by '|' symbol

> Usage: pm [options] [command]
>
> Commands:
>
> install|i [name]  install one or more packages
>
> other options ...

But when I run my own test application, my alias of command gets appended with the test application name itself and I get an output like this:

> Usage: index|r [options] [command]
>
> Commands:
>
> random      random command

Please notice that the alias 'r' is showing with index command instead of 'random' command. If I add more commands to my index.js file, the last alias gets appended to `Usage: index|<new alias>` instead of actually getting appended with the right command.

I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong. Can somebody please help here? How can I get the correct output when using the `-h` or `--help` option ?

**index.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
var program = require('commander');
program
  .version('1.0.0')
  .command('random', 'random command')
  .alias('r')
  .parse(process.argv);
```

**index-random.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
var program = require('commander');
program
  .option('-r, --random <random>', 'Random command option')
  .parse(process.argv);
```

**Package.json**

```
{
"name": "commander-test",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Testing commander",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "Raghuveer",
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"dependencies": {
  "commander": "^2.9.0",
  "graceful-readlink": "1.0.0"
 }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

```
node index -h
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add alias of the sub command to the corresponding sub command file. In your case you have to add it to **index-random.js** file like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
var program = require('commander');
program
  .option('-r, --random <random>', 'Random command option')
  .alias('r')
  .parse(process.argv);
```

Then when you invoke;    `node index.js help random`
the help will show `Usage: index-random|r`

However, the issue I am also facing is that if I call the index command only with alias, nothing will happen. (for ex: if I call `node index r` no output will return).

Let me know if you are successful in calling aliases instead of full command.

**Updated**: Below are the outputs of two commands.

```
>node index.js help

  Usage: index [options] [command]

  Commands:

    random      random command
    help [cmd]  display help for [cmd]

  Options:

    -h, --help     output usage information
    -V, --version  output the version number


>node index.js help random

  Usage: index-random|r [options]

  Options:

    -h, --help             output usage information
    -r, --random <random>  Random command option
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to this. I made the changes suggested by you but it didnt work. When I run node index -h, it still shows me `random      random command` instead of `random|r      random command`. What version of commander are you using ?

Comment: I also used `"commander": "^2.9.0"` configuration on my package.json file. For me also `node index.js help` does not show the alias. But when I call `node index.js help random` I could see the alias. I have edited my previous answer with outputs I get when I call two commands.